# How can I change the default x-axis title in love.plot of cobalt package in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axes

I would like to ask a simple question that I cannot find out the answer for. How can I change the default x-axis title in love.plot() ? I made several codes of ggplot2 that could be used for the same purpose but failed to replace the Default x-axis title with new one that I want.

My code for it was like follows :

```
love.plot(bal.tab(Procedure~Age+Gender+NYHA, data=impdata, weights='wt'), threshold = .1)
```

Comment: Have you tried something like this: `love.plot(...) + xlab("The new title")`?

Comment: love.plot() uses ggplot from the ggplot2 package, and (invisibly) returns a "ggplot" object. This means that users can edit aspects of the plot using ggplot2 syntax...from documentation....use scale_x_continuous(name = "name you want")

Comment: Can you please remove #cobalt tag? It is used for an application runtime software. https://www.cobalt.dev/

Comment: Hi Vincent and Daniel,  Thank you really much. Your codes did work. Actually, I had used it already before, but the problem was that I didn't call ggplot2 package for it. I thought that cobalt package was enough to do that. By the way, I just removed cobalt tag, Daniel.