# Change name of groups in bal.plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to visualize results from MatchIt procedure with `bal.plot()` from [cobalt package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cobalt/).

It works just fine, except I would like to change the lables for the group which by default are "Unadjusted sample" and "Adjusted sample".

```
bal.plot(AHEAD_nomiss, var.name = "KCH_TKS", which = "both",
         type = "histogram", mirror = F, 
         weights = AHEAD_nomiss$att.weights, treat = AHEAD_nomiss$group)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49873861/how-can-i-change-the-default-x-axis-title-in-love-plot-of-cobalt-package-in-r , the cobalt package uses ggplot2 as basis for plots.

Comment: I know it does, however the face wrap function is somehow build in function bal.plot and i cant figure out how to change labeller default settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author of `cobalt` package here. Thank you for using my package!

**Edit. Original post at the bottom.**

I just added some functionality to `bal.plot` for this in the development version of `cobalt`, which can be installed with `devtools::install_github("ngreifer/cobalt")`. Use the `sample.names` argument to supply a vector of names to give `bal.plot` and they'll appear in the facet labels. The vector should be as long as the number of samples (in your case, 2). Your new code should look like this:

```
bal.plot(AHEAD_nomiss, var.name = "KCH_TKS", which = "both",
         type = "histogram", mirror = F, 
         weights = AHEAD_nomiss$att.weights, treat = AHEAD_nomiss$group,
         sample.names = c("UNWEIGHTED", "WEIGHTED"))
```

Of course you can change the names. If you don't want to install the development version of `cobalt` (it't not guaranteed to be stable), you can use my solutions below.

---

I didn't intend `bal.plot` to be used for publication so I didn't make it super flexible, unlike `love.plot`. One thing you can do is manually program the histograms using `ggplot2`. Of course, this requires you learning how to use `ggplot2`, which can be a challenge, and looking at the source code of `bal.plot` probably won't help because of all the checks and transformations that occur. Here's some code that might work for you:

```
unweighted <- data.frame(KCH_TKS = AHEAD_nomiss$KCH_TKS,
                        treat = factor(AHEAD_nomiss$group),
                        weights = 1,
                        adj = "UNWEIGHTED",
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
weighted <- data.frame(KCH_TKS = AHEAD_nomiss$KCH_TKS,
                        treat = factor(AHEAD_nomiss$group),
                        weights = AHEAD_nomiss$att.weights,
                        adj = "WEIGHTED",
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data <- rbind(unweighted, weighted)

ggplot(data, aes(x = KCH_TKS, fill = treat)) + 
   geom_histogram(aes(weight = weights), bins = 10, alpha = .4, color = "black") + 
   facet_grid(~adj)
```

One way you can hack `bal.plot` is to provide a set of weights that are all equal to 1 as well as your desired weights and leave `which` at its default. If you give the weights names, those names will appear on the facet labels. So, for your example, try

```
bal.plot(AHEAD_nomiss, var.name = "KCH_TKS", 
         type = "histogram", mirror = F, 
         weights = list(UNWEIGHTED = rep(1, nrow(AHEAD_nomiss),
                        WEIGHTED = AHEAD_nomiss$att.weights), 
         treat = AHEAD_nomiss$group)
```

You should see that "UNWEIGHTED" and "WEIGHTED" are the new facet label names. You can of course change them to be whatever you want.